# If $\frac{x^2}{4}$ is an integer greater than 50, then what is the smallest possible value of $x^2$

Tags: solution-verification, integers

> If $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{4}$ is an integer greater than 50, then what is the smallest possible value of $x^2$ ?

IMO the answer should be $204$, the next small integer after $50$ is $51$, therefore, $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}4=51$ thus $x^2=204$. But the answer given is $256$, the question's answers considers the below constraint which I do not understand since my answer satisfies the constraints specifically given in the question.

The textbook answer states that given $x^2$ is divisible by $4$, so $x$ must be divisible by $2$ and even, thus answer given is $16\cdot16=256$. I understand that it should be divisible by $2$ but where does question state $x$ should also be an integer?

Comment: Does $x$ need to be an integer itself?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are correct.

Comment: I think you’re right. It seems that the GRE test expected the reader to *assume* $x$ is an integer without stating it. Your solution, however, meets all the information given in the question and is, of course, a smaller integer than 256. Too bad that you’d be penalized for being correct!

Comment: ETS, which administers both the GRE and the SAT, sometimes gets the answer wrong.